# C# - Play videos from resources in wmp component

Tags: c#, video, resources, wmp

I have a wmp component in a C# Windows Forms and i want it to play a video (.avi) from the solution's resources. I need to know the code for the wmp component to find the video. Suggestions?

Comment: Here come the downvotes...

Comment: What did you so far? Post some Code.

Comment: @Brian always the same -.-

Comment: Don't forget to add `using WMPLib;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is a way over streaming the file.

First of all, we need a place where it should be always possible

```
        string streamPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\";
```

Next Step an Instance of the MediaPlayer

```
    WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
```

Then we need to stream the Assembly Resource

```
    Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Smartis.Resources.Natur.wmv");

    using (Stream output = new FileStream (streamPath + "mediafile.avi", FileMode.Create))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32*1024];
        int read;

        while ( (read= stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

Finally we should be able to load the file.

```
    wmp.URL = streamPath + "mediafile.avi";
    wmp.controls.play();
```

---

After playing don't forget to clear the folder:

```
    File.Delete(streamPath + "mediafile.avi");
```

Comment: This won't work because the video is not located in an URL, it's in the resources of the program

Comment: Gentlemen, you had my curiosity. But now you have my attention. Upvote