# Atatch media files to my publish program (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, publish

Im using vb2008.
I want to publish my program . I need to add some  media sources files to my program.
I added them to the resources tab but when I run the exe program, they dont rise up.
Where should I put them ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on `media sources files`, what kind of files, where do you want them to go when published?

Comment: I have pictures ,sound files  and video files. when I run my program in vb2008 it start to play the movie file and play sound file. in the exe. program it wont play.  I put all the files in the resource tab of the compiler.

Comment: Do the pictures display? and does the sound work? or it's just the video that's not playing?

Comment: @djv yes sound and pic are fine. I have problome to add media files only to the wmp control from the resource

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410483/832052) help?

Comment: @djv I installed it on c: driver and copy manually the clip to the app folder. lame but works